# adding capacitor plugin is causing errors to quasar application with vite

Tags: vue.js, vite, capacitor, quasar-framework, commonjs

I'm trying to add [tchvu3/capacitor-voice-recorder](https://github.com/tchvu3/capacitor-voice-recorder) to my project. I followed the doc's suggestion and installed it in src-capacitor and imported like so

```js
import { VoiceRecorder } from 'capacitor-voice-recorder'
```

It worked and I moved on implementing other code related to that plugin. The next day I continued work on the project only to get

`Failed to resolve import "capacitor-voice-recorder"`

so I added

```ts
"paths": {
      "myapp/*": ["*"],
      "capacitor-voice-recorder/": ["./src-capacitor/node_modules/capacitor-voice-recorder/"]
    }
```

to tsconfig.json and

```js
 alias: {
        'capacitor-voice-recorder': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src-capacitor/node_modules/capacitor-voice-recorder'),
      }
```

to quasar.config.js and that resulted in a new error

`SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default`

the vite docs mention

`CommonJS dependencies should not be excluded from optimization.`

so I added vite.config.ts

```ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['./src-capacitor/node_modules/capacitor-voice-recorder/*'],
  },
})
```

nothing changed. so what do I do now? would appreciate any suggestions. what is crazy is that it used to work and the plugin worked on web, android (on a physical device) and ios mobile emulator, how come it stopped working all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by adding the following to `quasar.config.js` instead of creating `vite.config.ts`

````js
      extendViteConf (viteConf) {
        viteConf.optimizeDeps.include = [
          'capacitor-voice-recorder',
        ];
      },```
````